# FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, .........)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

i'm a beginner in unity and i have a problem in my project, i'm more precise, there's a problem in the checkpoint script and this result

error:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) (at \<695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749\>:0)
System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles style, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at \<695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749\>:0)
System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) (at \<695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749\>:0)
Checkpoint.Start () (at Assets/Script/Checkpoint.cs:38)
```

I hope you guys can help me to solve this problem and this is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Checkpoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public int lap = 0;
    [HideInInspector]
    public int checkPoint = -1;
    int checkPointCount;
    int nextCheckpoint = 0;
    Dictionary<int, bool> visited = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
    public Text lapText;
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool missed = false;
    public GameObject PrevCheckpoint;

    //Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject[] checkpoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Checkpoint");
        checkPointCount = checkpoints.Length;
    
        foreach (GameObject checpoint in checkpoints)
        {
            if (checpoint.name == "0")
            {
                PrevCheckpoint = checpoint;
                break;
            }
        }
    
        foreach (GameObject cp in checkpoints)
        {
            visited.Add(Int32.Parse(cp.name), false);
        }
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame (eror lap gak mau nambah)
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        Debug.Log("colision");
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Checkpoint")
        {
            int checkpointCurrent = int.Parse(col.gameObject.name);
    
            if (checkpointCurrent == nextCheckpoint)
            {
                PrevCheckpoint = col.gameObject;
                visited[checkpointCurrent] = true;
                checkPoint = checkpointCurrent;
                if (checkPoint == 0 && gameObject.tag == "Player")
                {
                    lap++;
                    lapText.text = "Lap: " + lap;
                }
    
                nextCheckpoint++;
                if (nextCheckpoint >= checkPointCount)
                {
                    var keys = new List<int>(visited.Keys);
                    foreach (int key in keys)
                    {
                        visited[key] = false;
                    }
                    nextCheckpoint = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that at least one of your checkpoint names is not an integer, so the parsing of it fails.

Comment: You could use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) instead to figure out where it fails and log some information that can help you track it down.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

```
int checkpointCurrent = int.Parse(col.gameObject.name);
```

The Method `int.Parse()` trys to convert a string like say `"123"` to a number like `123`.

But if the String contains letters like say `"12b3"`, `"b"` is hardly a number, thus the error.

As @Retired Ninja pointed in the comments out, you should use `[TryParse][1]` instead.